# Toggle touchpad map to hotkey

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, touchpad, 18.10

My laptop does not have a `fn`+`touchpad` key.
I found the toggle in the system settings. But I'm looking for a hotkey.
How can I create a shortcut to toggle the touchpad off and on?

Did I mis a setting or do I need a custom command?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 with default Gnome-3.

**Update:** for anyone wondering I've also opened a [issue on gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/issues/395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this do it?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events disabled
```

Comment: Yes that works, now I'll just wrap it up in a bash script and then I've created something is part of pretty much every OS/desktopenv...

Comment: huzzah! \o/ happy to help!